# JFrame child cannot see parent widgits

Tags: java, swing, oop

I have a JFrame application with some variables and a number of SWING widgets. In it I create an instance of another class and pass the JFrame to the child in the constructor.  From the child, I can reference the variables, but not the widgets.  Why?

```
 // My JFrame
 public class Prot2Prom extends JFrame  {

    // My Child
    public Prot2Prom() {
    super( "Protocol To PROM" );
        Child child = new Child(this);
```

In the Child class my constructor does

```
 Prot2Prom frame = null;

 public Child(Prot2Prom gui) {
    frame = gui;
 }
```

The following works:

```
 frame.<parent variable>=x;
```

The following does not:

```
 frame.textArea.append("Hello");
```

The textArea cannot be resolved.  There were all added with "new".  Why can't I see them?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notes and recommendations:

- This has nothing to do with "widgets" or Swing and all to do with visibility of variables. I'm guessing that `textArea` is not a *public* field of the Prot2Prom class.
- If variables are public outside classes can "see" them, access them, modify them.
- A possible solution is to in fact make the variables that you want other classes to see, public.
- In general you really **don't** want to do this.
- Instead much better is to give a class public methods that allow other classes to call and by doing so alter the original class's behavior. In other words, your Swing GUI classes should adhere to good OOPs principles just as any Java class should.
- Later you'll want to read up on the MVC or **M**odel, **V**iew, **C**ontrol design pattern as a way of separating out behaviors of your code into separate logical entities, which can make your code much more flexible and powerful.

**Edit 1**
Regarding your comment:

> The "widgets" are all created by WindowsBuilder Pro. I am trying to use the textArea to create my Eclipse Console for a stand alone (jar) application. How can I print to it from a class instantiated by the Frame?

You'll want to give the class that holds the textArea variable a public method:

```
public void appendTextAreaText(String text) {
  textArea.append(text);
}
```

Then your other classes can append text to the JTextArea. Why is this important? One reason is that if the class that holds textArea will at some times not want to allow other classes the ability to append to this widget, it can have the logic to control this in the method. Thus it gives much more control over the widget to the class that holds it.

e.g.,

```
public void appendTextAreaText(String text) {
  if (allowTextAreaAppend) {  // a class boolean field 
    textArea.append(text);
  }
}
```

As an aside, I also recommend that you put the code generation tool to the side and instead create your Swing GUI's by hand for a bit until you get a firm grasp of Swing and Java fundamentals. This will make your future use of the Swing code generation tool much better and productive.

Comment: The "widgets" are all created by WindowsBuilder Pro.  I am trying to use the textArea to create my Eclipse Console for a stand alone (jar) application.  How can I print to it from a class instantiated by the Frame?

Comment: Since your original remarks, I had created a public void logText(String s) which simply did a textArea.append(s).  This method in the JFrame still cannot resolve textArea.  You were calling it a "variable", but is is still just a JTextArea.  Unlike a JTextField which can take a value from a variable, the JTextArea wants me to append.  I just cannot figure out how to get a hold of it!

Comment: @mkst: then you need to show us the code where it is declared in your class.

Comment: JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(false); public void logText(String s) {
  textArea.append(s);
 }

Comment: @mkst: no, we can't tell anything about that, about whether this is being declared at the class level or in a method or constructor. Much better would be for you to edit your original question and show how textArea is declared and **where** textArea is declared.

Comment: I may have just found part of the answer.  At the end of the window that implemented the JFrame in the example I am borrowing from, there is a commend // Variables declaration - do not modify // GEN-BEGIN:variables.  This list includes public javax.swing.JTextArea txtLog.  I think this is why that applications works.  What tool generated this block of declarations?

Comment: @mkst: So you don't even have a variable named textArea that is being displayed?? You already know what generated this block of declarations, your WindowsBuilder Pro code generator. Again, I advise you not to use this until you've got a little more Swing under your belt.

Comment: I will take that suggestion to heart.  Needless to say, you wont' be hearing from me for a while, but thank you for all of your input.

Comment: @mkstlwtz *I had created a public void logText(String s) ... JFrame still cannot resolve textArea* It sounds like the `JTextArea` is being declared within the method that creates it, meaning that it has no scope outside of that method.  In order for it to accessible, the text area must be declared at class level, making it accessible to the rest of the class...I believe Reimeus's example states as much

Answer (score 2):

> The textArea cannot be resolved

This message indicates that there is no member class variable called `textArea` in `Prot2Prom`. This is possibly a typo. Perhaps the variable is called `textarea` or defined only locally in the constructor scope.

To work your class would look something like this

```
public class Prot2Prom extends JFrame {

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    ...
```

A better approach to updating text in a parent component is to create a method to `Prot2Prom` like so:

```
public void addText(String text) {
   textArea.append(text);
}
```

This provides more control over how text is added to the `JTextArea`.